# Refrence error for iscrollview and iscroll js

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll, iscrollview

Hi i am a newbie in javascript and jquery i am building a phonegap application .

In my application i am trying to implement the pull to refresh feature using the iscroll and iscrollview as demoed in the site http://www.x-services.nl/category/phonegap-cordova

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Event Info</title>
<style>

.ui-page {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    } 



#navgroup {text-align:center;}
#navgroup div {display:inline-block;}


        .nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner { padding-top: 40px !important; }
        .nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-icon { width: 30px!important; height: 30px!important; margin-left: -15px !important; box-shadow: none!important; -moz-box-shadow: none!important; -webkit-box-shadow: none!important; -webkit-border-radius: none !important; border-radius: none !important; }
        #chat .ui-icon { background:  url(images/icons/09-chat-2.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: 24px 22px; }
        #email .ui-icon { background:  url(images/icons/18-envelope.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: 24px 16px;  }
        #login .ui-icon { background:  url(images/icons/30-key.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;  background-size: 12px 26px; }
        #beer .ui-icon { background:  url(images/icons/88-beermug.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;  background-size: 22px 27px; }
        #coffee .ui-icon { background:  url(images/icons/100-coffee.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;  background-size: 20px 24px; }
        #skull .ui-icon { background:  url(images/icons/21-skull.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;  background-size: 22px 24px; }



</style>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobiscroll.custom-2.5.4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mobiscroll.custom-2.5.4.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/iscroll.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/indexinfo.js"></script>


<!--  script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date.js"></script> -->
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>

</head>
<body id="body">
<div id="plistview" data-role="page" >

    <script src="scripts/date.js"></script>
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" id="header" data-theme="a">
    <!--  <a id="calendarlink" href="calendarview.html" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-left" data-ajax="false">Calendar</a> 
    <a id="calendarlink" data-role="button" href="#" data-icon="calendar" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="slideup" data-prefetch="true"></a>
    <a id="filterlink" data-role="button" href="#pfilterview" data-icon="filter" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="slideup" data-prefetch="true"></a>   
    -->

    <div class="ui-btn-right">
        <a id="calendarlink" href="calendarview.html"  data-role="button" data-icon="calendar"  data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide">Calendar</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="list" class="ui-btn-active" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">list</a>  
        <a href="#pfilterview" data-role="button" data-icon="filter" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-transition="slideup" data-inline="true">filter</a>
    </div>
    <h1>Event Info</h1> 

</div>
         <p id="paragraph"></p>

<div id="middlecontent" data-role="content" data-iscroll>         
    <div class="iscroll-pulldown">
       <span class="iscroll-pull-icon"></span>
       <span class="iscroll-pull-label"
             data-iscroll-loading-text="News is being refreshed"
             data-iscroll-pulled-text="Release to refresh the news">
         Refresh the news
       </span>
     </div>

    <div id="eventlist"> 
    <!--  <a id="getpreviouseventsbutton" href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" >Get previous events</a> -->
    <br>            
        <ul id="upcomingevents" data-role="listview"  data-inset="true">
            <li>one</li>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>one</li>            
        </ul>
        <br>        
           <!-- <a id="getmoreeventsbutton" href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" >Get next month events</a>   -->   
    </div>


<br> <br> <br> <br>
</div>


<div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">       
        <div id="navgroup" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">

            <a id="listlink" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" >List</a>
            <a id="calendarlink" href="calendarview.html" data-role="button" data-icon=""  data-transition="slide">Month</a>          
        </div>
         <!--  <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a id="listlink" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" >List</a></li>
            <li><a id="calendarlink" href="calendarview.html" data-role="button" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-center"  data-transition="slide">Calendar</a></li>      
        </ul>
        -->
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<div id="pfilterview" data-role="page" >

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).one("pageshow",'#pfilterview',function(){
    console.log("category list is loading");

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
        complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner
        url: 'http://linuxweb.symsoft.local/ycal/index.php/event/Categories?callback=test',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function( arr ) {              
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

                            $('#categories').append( '<label><input class="selectedcategory" value="'+arr[i].category+'" name="'+arr[i].category+'" type="checkbox">'+arr[i].category+'</label>').trigger( "create" );                                                                                                                              

                }// this logic assumes that the data is in ascending order by date      

                //code to fill the event list page ends  
        //$('#upcomingevents').listview('refresh');
        },
        error: function( data ) {
          console.log( "error" );
          alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
        }
      });   
});

$(document).on('click','#apply',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    filteredcategories=[];
    $('#categorylist :checked').each(function() {
        filteredcategories.push($(this).val());
         });

    console.log("filtered values -> "+filteredcategories);  
    updatelistview();

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectbutton').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $(this).val('Deselect all').button('refresh');
    },function(){       
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $(this).val('Select all').button('refresh');        
    })
});


</script>

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="flase">
    <a href="#plistview" id="apply" ..data-icon="" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="slidedown">Cancel</a>
    <a href="#" id="apply" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="slidedown">Apply</a>
    <h1>Filter</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">       
        <div id="categorylist">                 
        <form id="categories">
        <input class="check" id="selectbutton" type='button' value="Select All">            
        </form>
        <br><br>
        <a href="#plistview" id="apply" data-icon="" data-role="button" data-mini="true"  data-transition="slidedown">Apply</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="flase">

    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

I get  ReferenceError: iScroll is not defined
jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js
Line 259 which points to iscrollview.js i am unable to figure out the reason for this reference error.

The line is _subclass(IScroll,iScroll) the iScroll is undefined . Here iScroll var is a superconstructor type var 
I fail to understand the reason for this cause

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but in the iscroll.js in line 1973 is as window.IScroll = IScroll;

I think this is wrong.

The right is window.iScroll = IScroll;

I change and worked for me.

Comment: Probably we use a diferente version of icroll, because iscrollview is designed (actually ) for iscroll version 4.2.5. I tried in 5.1 and i had change the line 1973

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this a "Strange Error" it appears you have not included all of the JS files in your app that you are referencing in your `<script>` tags at the top.

Comment: Hi @Tyler yea i understand the cause of the error but only 2 scripts are required the iscroll and iscrollview apart from the jquery and jquery mobile i have all the scripts in place but even then it gives me reference error and the error is in the iscrollview js file

Comment: @user2453350 can't really help you without seeing your setup, but you've got something wrong somewhere. Note that if you are using iScrollView widget 1.3.2 (latest - https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview/blob/master/lib/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js) that you also need to use iScroll 4.1.9 or later (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)

Comment: Remember that order matters, how you order including your JS scripts is important. Also, in the example code you pasted above you are including the phonegap JS in a weird place.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code i will try to figure out what is happening

Comment: I am using the latest zip for both the iscroll and iscrollview.